# Python classes IndexError

Tags: python, class

I wrote this class to weave two rows together.

```
class CoordinatRow(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.coordinaterow = []

def add_coordinaterow(self, coordinate):
    self.coordinaterow.append(coordinate)    


def weave(self,other):
    lijst = []
    for i in range(len(self.coordinaterow)):
        lijst.append(self.coordinaterow[i])
        lijst.append(other.coordinaterow[i]) 
    self.coordinaterow = lijst
    return self.coordinaterow
```

I add coordinates to the object like this:

```
def process_row(line):                                 
  temp_coordinate_row = CoordinatRow()
  rij = line.split()
  for coordinate in rij:
     coor = process_coordinate(coordinate)
     temp_coordinate_row.add_coordinaterow(coor)
  return temp_coordinate_row
```

How ever when i want to add 2 rows together by doing this:

```
def split_and_add(invoer):                             
    rij = invoer.split('=')
    rows = []
    for line in rij:
        rows.append(process_row(line))
    return rows


bestand = file_input()
rows = split_and_add(bestand)
for row in range(0,len(rows)-1):
    rows[row].weave(rows[row+1])
```

However i get the follwing error:

```
rows[row].weave(rows[row+1])  
lijst.append(other.coordinaterow[i]) 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: You have 2 lines there which is actually causing the issue?

Comment: it is lijst.append(other.coordinaterow[i]) that is causin the problem

Comment: Ahh so your self list is longer than your other list.

Comment: yes thats it, do you know how i could alter the function to make it work?

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste your exception with traceback, instead of approximating it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this to fix it:

```
for i in range(len(self.coordinaterow)):
    lijst.append(self.coordinaterow[i])
    try:
        lijst.append(other.coordinaterow[i])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks the error is gone, however when i try to print the outcome i looks like this:   [<Coordinates.Coordinate object at 0x021E5630>, <Coordinates.Coordinate object at 0x021E56D0>] whould you know what is causing that?

Comment: How and where are you trying to print the outcome?

Comment: i put the output objects in a variable and print that variable

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but if you take that `variable` and do `print variable[0].coordinaterow` does that give you what you expect/want?

Comment: @Pieter: That's a separate problem that you really should ask separately, not as a followup comment to the solution to your first problem. But the answer is pretty simple: You haven't defined a `__repr__` or `__str__` for your `Coordinate` class, so that's the default string representation you get.